# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object

Tags: java, localhost, classloader, noclassdeffounderror

So I have my own classloader class `ServerLoader` which is able to load classes from the local server with path `http://localhost/app/1/` where are some .class files exist. But my program crashes when I try to define byte code of some class.

```
result = defineClass(name, ByteClass, 0, ByteClass.length);
```

So I am getting a `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object`

Here is the whole class:

```
package com.local;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ServerLoader extends ClassLoader {

    private ClassLoader parent;
    private String urlPath;

    public ServerLoader(String urlPath) {
        parent = ServerLoader.class.getClassLoader();
        this.urlPath = urlPath;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {

        Class<?> result = null;

        try {
            URL mainUrl = new URL(urlPath + name.substring(11);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) mainUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());

            int data;
            while ((data = input.read()) != -1) {
                out.write(data);
            }

            byte[] ByteClass = out.toByteArray();
            result = defineClass(name, ByteClass, 0, ByteClass.length);
            cacheClass.put(result.getName(), result);
            return result;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

So here is main method

```
package com.local;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ServerLoader loader = new ServerLoader("http://localhost/app/1/");

        Class<?> remoteInstanceClass = loader.loadClass("com.server.PluginA");

        Method mainMethod = remoteInstanceClass.getMethod("main", String[].class);
        mainMethod.invoke(remoteInstanceClass, (Object) args);
    }
}
```

And stack trace

```
com.local.Main
    Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:54553', transport: 'socket'
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost/app/1/Object.class
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1836)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
        at com.local.ServerLoader.ConnectAndResolveClass(ServerLoader.java:43)
        at com.local.ServerLoader.loadClass(ServerLoader.java:28)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
        at com.local.ServerLoader.ConnectAndResolveClass(ServerLoader.java:51)
        at com.local.ServerLoader.loadClass(ServerLoader.java:28)
        at com.local.Main.main(Main.java:10)
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
        at com.local.ServerLoader.ConnectAndResolveClass(ServerLoader.java:51)
        at com.local.ServerLoader.loadClass(ServerLoader.java:28)
        at com.local.Main.main(Main.java:10)
    Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:54553', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

All pathes and names are correct. So what can cause the problem?

Comment: If the path names are correct, are you saying that the file `http://localhost/app/1/Object.class` exists? Otherwise the paths are not correct.

Comment: What is an example of a class that does work?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. Every ClassLoader in `LoadClass` method must at first load the class using parent ClassLoader and then try to load it in another way. So this is correct LoadClass method.

```
@Override
public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {

    Class<?> result = null;

    try {
        result = parent.loadClass(name);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        try {
            URL mainURL = new URL(urlPath + name.substring(name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1) + ".class");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) mainURL.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());

            int data;
            while ((data = input.read()) != -1) {
                out.write(data);
            }

            byte[] byteClass = out.toByteArray();
            result = defineClass(name, byteClass, 0, byteClass.length);

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

You asked about example class:

```
package com.server;

public class PluginE {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Executing main method of PluginE");

    }
}
```